# Getting raw microphone data on the Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, microphone

Is it possible to obtain raw microphone data on the Windows Phone 7 to measure the ambient sound? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

not sure if you are familiar with Dealing with micrphone in WP7 or not 
but you can check this [blog post](http://cisforcoder.wordpress.com/2010/08/21/recording-audio-in-silverlight-on-windows-phone-7/) for a full detailed tutorial :

you initialize a buffer with the size of the data :

```
_buffer = new byte[_microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(_microphone.BufferDuration)];
```

and whenever the Microphone data is ready in this event handler get the data from the microphone add it to the Buffer then you can do anything using it :

```
  private void MicrophoneBufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _microphone.GetData(_buffer);
        //Do something with the data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    }
```

you'll need to include and everything is stated in the tutorial in Details

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is here:

http://library.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_access_and_manage_the_Microphone_raw_data_in_WP7