# microsoft xna framework microphone sound format on wp8

Tags: c#, .net, azure, windows-phone-8, xna

What is the file format for recording with microphone using xna framework on windows phone 8?

After that buffer writes into stream:

```
Microphone microphone = Microphone.Default;

        microphone.GetData(bufferz);
```

[Getting raw microphone data on the Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116577/getting-raw-microphone-data-on-the-windows-phone)

Answer (score 0):

The audio format is in PCM wave data, also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434119.aspx

Comment: so? what can we say about this ? data:audio/aac;base64,  aac or PCM or wav?